# How can I change multiple entries in DB?

Tags: magento2, database, model, sql

In DB I have 
**Rows:**

```
ID NAME PHONE
```

**Example:**

```
1 Steave 33333333
2 Joe 77777
```

I can add and Edit any row, but I want when I click "**save everyone**"  I rewrote all phones on DB
example:

```
1 Steave 33333333
    2 Joe 77777
```

click "edit Joe"
- >>> XML Form
rewrote phone on "555555"
Click "**save everyone**" 
- >>> Controller\Adminthml\Slider\SaveEvryone.php

```
- DO THIS
```

but how?
If I want to rewrote one item,  I create model

```
 $model = $this->userFactory->create();
```

after

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('user_id');
        if ($id) {
            try {
                $model = $this->sliderRepository->getById($id);
            } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This slider no longer exists.'));
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }
        }
$model->setData($data);
$this->sliderRepository->save($model);
```

but dont know how rewrite some models :[